# 4e Essentials and mounted combat

Tags: character-creation, dnd-4e, mounted-combat, fighter

I'm creating a fighter for a 4e D&D Essentials game. I'd like to model him after a European medieval knight, but a knight is less than complete without a good horse. What are the rules for a knight under 4e Essentials? I have the Red Box and I couldn't find anything in there, unless I overlooked it. If we don't have published rules/attack bonuses yet for Essentials, does one of the PHBs contain the mounted combat rules?

Comment: I got the Hero's of the fallen lands and it has a small section on mounts and combat, although no stat's are provided. I'll find the page numbers later as I don't have the book with me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Rules Compendium* page 252 has the rules for Mounted Combat. But has no mount stats. For that a D&DI subscription or the *Adventurer's Vault*  or one of the Monster type books is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Also Page 199 in the PHB,

Short story is once you have the feat (named appropiately enough Mounted Combat) and you ride a creature you gain access to any special mount abilties it confers on its rider. The Monster Manuals have the details for those special powers (contained under the appropiate monster heading).

You are also allowed to use some skills in place of your mounts skills (athletics, acrobatics, endurance, stealth).